# Why are web apps going crazy with await / async nowadays?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I come from a back end / thick client background, so maybe I'm missing something... but I recently looked at the source for an open source JWT token server and the authors went crazy with await / async. Like on every method and every line.

I get what the pattern is for... to run long running tasks in a separate thread. In my thick client days, I would use it if a method might take a few seconds, so as not to block the GUI thread... but definitely not on a method that takes a few ms.

Is this excessive use of await / async something you need for web dev or for something like Angular? This was in a JWT token server, so not even seeing what it has to do with any of those. It's just a REST end point.

How is making every single line async going to improve performace? To me, it'll kill performance from spinning up all those threads, no?

Comment: One of the main reasons for multithread programing was to provide solution for long IO operations. But implementing whole IO asynchronous model could be difficult task not mention time consuming. .net give you a simple solution for this `Task` and to even more simplify two new keyword `await` and `async`. And when things are simple people start to abuse them for the sake of even more simplification as they don't want to think about them anymore when they use them.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

> I get what the pattern is for... to run long running tasks in a separate thread.

**This is absolutely not what this pattern is for**.

Await does *not* put the operation on a new thread. Make sure that is *very* clear to you.  **Await schedules the remaining work as the continuation of the high latency operation.**

Await does *not* make a synchronous operation into an asynchronous concurrent operation.  **Await enables programmers who are working with a model that is already asynchronous to write their logic to resemble synchronous workflows**. Await neither creates nor destroys asynchrony; it *manages* existing asynchrony.

Spinning up a new thread is like hiring a worker.  When you await a task, you are not hiring a worker to do that task.  You are asking "is this task already done? If not, call me back when its done so I can keep doing work that depends on that task.  In the meanwhile, I'm going to go work on this other thing over here..."

If you're doing your taxes and you find you need a number from your work, and the mail hasn't arrived yet, you don't **hire a worker to wait by the mailbox**.  You make a note of where you were in your taxes, go get other stuff done, and when the mail comes, you pick up where you left off.  That's *await*. It's *asynchronously waiting for a result*.

> Is this excessive use of await / async something you need for web dev or for something like Angular?

It's to manage latency.

> How is making every single line async going to improve performance?

In two ways. First, by ensuring that applications remain responsive in a world with high-latency operations. That kind of performance is important to users who don't want their apps to hang.  Second, by providing developers with tools for expressing the data dependency relationships in asynchronous workflows.  By not blocking on high-latency operations, system resources are freed up to work on unblocked operations.

> To me, it'll kill performance from spinning up all those threads, no?

There are no threads. Concurrency is a mechanism for achieving asynchrony; it is not the only one.

> Ok, so if I write code like: await someMethod1(); await someMethod2(); await someMethod3(); that is magically going to make the app more responsive?

More responsive compared to what?  Compared to calling those methods without awaiting them?  No, of course not.  Compared to synchronously waiting for the tasks to complete?  Absolutely, yes.

> That's what I'm not getting I guess. If you awaited on all 3 at the end, then yeah, you're running the 3 methods in parallel.

No no no. Stop thinking about parallelism.  There need not be any parallelism.

Think about it this way.  You wish to make a fried egg sandwich.  You have the following tasks:

- Fry an egg
- Toast some bread
- Assemble a sandwich

Three tasks. The third task depends on the results of the first two, but the first two tasks do not depend on each other.  So, here are some workflows:

- Put an egg in the pan. While the egg is frying, stare at the egg.
- Once the egg is done, put some toast in the toaster.  Stare at the toaster.
- Once the toast is done, put the egg on the toast.

The problem is that you could be putting the toast in the toaster while the egg is cooking. Alternative workflow:

- Put an egg in the pan. Set an alarm that rings when the egg is done.
- Put toast in the toaster. Set an alarm that rings when the toast is done.
- Check your mail. Do your taxes. Polish the silverware.  Whatever it is you need to do.
- When both alarms have rung, grab the egg and the toast, put them together, and you have a sandwich.

Do you see why the asynchronous workflow is far more efficient? You get lots of stuff done while you're waiting for the high latency operation to complete.  **But you did not hire an egg chef and a toast chef**. There are no new threads!

The workflow I proposed would be:

```
eggtask = FryEggAsync();
toasttask = MakeToastAsync();
egg = await eggtask;
toast = await toasttask;
return MakeSandwich(egg, toast);
```

Now, compare that to:

```
eggtask = FryEggAsync();
egg = await eggtask;
toasttask = MakeToastAsync();
toast = await toasttask;
return MakeSandwich(egg, toast);
```

Do you see how that workflow differs? This workflow is:

- Put an egg in the pan and set an alarm.
- Go do other work until the alarm goes off.
- Get the egg out of the pan; put the bread in the toaster. Set an alarm...
- Go do other work until the alarm goes off.
- When the alarm goes off, assemble the sandwich.

This workflow is less efficient *because we have failed to capture the fact that the toast and egg tasks are high latency and independent*.  But it is surely more efficient use of resources than doing *nothing* while you're waiting for the egg to cook.

The point of this whole thing is: threads are insanely expensive, so *don't* spin up new threads.  Rather, *make more efficient use of the thread you've got by putting it to work while you're doing high latency operations*.  Await is *not* about spinning up new threads; it is about getting more work done on one thread in a world with high latency computation.

Maybe that computation is being done on another thread, maybe it's blocked on disk, whatever. Doesn't matter. The point is, await is for *managing* that asynchrony, not *creating* it.

> I'm having a difficult time understanding how asynchronous programming can be possible without using parallelism somewhere. Like, how do you tell the program to get started on the toast while waiting for the eggs without DoEggs() running concurrently, at least internally?

Go back to the analogy. You are making an egg sandwich, the eggs and toast are cooking, and so you start reading your mail. You get halfway through the mail when the eggs are done, so you put the mail aside and take the egg off the heat. Then you go back to the mail. Then the toast is done and you make the sandwich. Then you finish reading your mail after the sandwich is made. **How did you do all that without hiring staff, one person to read the mail, one person to cook the egg, one to make the toast and one to assemble the sandwich?** You did it all with a single worker.

How did you do that? By breaking tasks up into small pieces, noting which pieces have to be done in which order, and then *cooperatively multitasking* the pieces.

Kids today with their big flat virtual memory models and multithreaded processes think that this is how its always been, but my memory stretches back to the days of Windows 3, which had none of that. If you wanted two things to happen "in parallel" that's what you did: split the tasks up into small parts and took turns executing parts. The whole operating system was based on this concept.

Now, you might look at the analogy and say "OK, but some of the work, like actually toasting the toast, is being done by a machine", and *that* is the source of parallelism.  Sure, I didn't have to hire a worker to toast the bread, but I achieved parallelism in hardware.  And that is the right way to think of it.  **Hardware parallelism and thread parallelism are different**.  When you make an asynchronous request to the network subsystem to go find you a record from a database, there is *no thread* that is sitting there waiting for the result. The hardware achieves parallelism at a level far, far below that of operating system threads.

If you want a more detailed explanation of how hardware works with the operating system to achieve asynchrony, read "[There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)" by Stephen Cleary.

So when you see "async" do not think "parallel".  Think "high latency operation split up into small pieces" If there are *many* such operations whose pieces do not depend on each other then you can *cooperatively interleave* the execution of those pieces on one thread.

As you might imagine, it is *very difficult* to write control flows where you can abandon what you are doing right now, go do something else, and seamlessly pick up where you left off. That's why we make the compiler do that work! The point of "await" is that it lets you manage those asynchronous workflows by describing them as synchronous workflows. Everywhere that there is a point where you could put this task aside and come back to it later, write "await".  The compiler will take care of turning your code into many tiny pieces that can each be scheduled in an asynchronous workflow.

UPDATE:

> In your last example, what would be the difference between

---

```
eggtask = FryEggAsync(); 
egg = await eggtask; 
toasttask = MakeToastAsync(); 
toast = await toasttask;
```

---

```
egg = await FryEggAsync(); 
toast = await MakeToastAsync();?
```

---

> I assume it calls them synchronously but executes them asynchronously? I have to admit I've never even bothered to await the task separately before.

There is no difference.

When `FryEggAsync` is called, it is **called** regardless of whether `await` appears before it or not.  `await` is an **operator**. It operates on the thing **returned** from the call to `FryEggAsync`.  It's just like any other operator.

Let me say this again:  `await` is an **operator** and its operand is a task.  It is a very unusual operator, to be sure, but grammatically it is an operator, and it operates on a *value* just like any other operator.

Let me say it again: `await` is not magic dust that you put on a call site and suddenly that call site is remoted to another thread.  The call happens when the call happens, the call returns a **value**, and that value is *a reference to an object that is a legal operand to the `await` operator*.

So yes,

```
var x = Foo();
var y = await x;
```

and

```
var y = await Foo();
```

are the same thing, the same as

```
var x = Foo();
var y = 1 + x;
```

and

```
var y = 1 + Foo();
```

are the same thing.

So let's go through this one more time, because you seem to believe the myth that `await` *causes* asynchrony.  It does not.

```
async Task M() { 
   var eggtask = FryEggAsync();
```

Suppose `M()` is called. `FryEggAsync` is called. Synchronously. There is no such thing as an asynchronous call; you see a call, control passes to the callee until the callee returns.  The callee returns *a task which represents an egg to be made available in the future*.

How does `FryEggAsync` do this?  I don't know and I don't care.  All I know is I call it, and I get an object back that represents a future value. Maybe that value is produced on a different thread. Maybe it is produced on *this thread* but *in the future*. Maybe it is produced by special-purpose hardware, like a disk controller or a network card. I don't care. I care that I get back a task.

```
  egg = await eggtask;
```

Now we take that task and `await` asks it "are you done?" If the answer is yes, then `egg` is given the value produced by the task.  If the answer is no then `M()` returns a `Task` representing "the work of M will be completed in the future".  The remainder of M() is signed up as the continuation of `eggtask`, so when `eggtask` completes, it will call `M()` again and pick it up *not from the beginning*, but from *the assignment to `egg`*.  M() is a *resumable at any point* method. The compiler does the necessary magic to make that happen.

So now we've returned. The thread keeps on doing whatever it does. At some point the egg is ready, so the continuation of `eggtask` is invoked, which causes `M()` to be called again. It resumes at the point where it left off: assigning the just-produced egg to `egg`.  And now we keep on trucking:

```
toasttask = MakeToastAsync();
```

Again, the call returns a task, and we:

```
toast = await toasttask;
```

check to see if the task is complete. If yes, we assign `toast`. If no, then *we return from M() again*, and the *continuation* of `toasttask` is *the remainder of M().

And so on.

Eliminating the `task` variables does nothing germane. Storage for the values is allocated; it's just not given a name.

ANOTHER UPDATE:

> is there a case to be made to call Task-returning methods as early as possible but awaiting them as late as possible?

The example given is something like:

```
var task = FooAsync();
DoSomethingElse();
var foo = await task;
...
```

There is *some* case to be made for that. But let's take a step back here.  The purpose of the `await` operator is *to construct an asynchronous workflow using the coding conventions of a synchronous workflow*. So the thing to think about is *what is that workflow*?  A *workflow* imposes an ordering upon a set of related tasks.

The easiest way to see the ordering required in a workflow is to examine the *data dependence*. You can't make the sandwich before the toast comes out of the toaster, so you're going to have to obtain the toast *somewhere*. Since await extracts the value from the completed task, there's got to be an await *somewhere* between the creation of the toaster task and the creation of the sandwich.

You can also represent dependencies on side effects. For example, the user presses the button, so you want to play the siren sound, then wait three seconds, then open the door, then wait three seconds, then close the door:

```
DisableButton();
PlaySiren();
await Task.Delay(3000);
OpenDoor();
await Task.Delay(3000);
CloseDoor();
EnableButton();
```

It would make no sense at all to say

```
DisableButton();
PlaySiren();
var delay1 = Task.Delay(3000);
OpenDoor();
var delay2 = Task.Delay(3000);
CloseDoor();
EnableButton();
await delay1;
await delay2;
```

Because this is not the desired workflow.

So, the actual answer to your question is: deferring the await until the point where the value is actually needed is a pretty good practice, because it increases the opportunities for work to be scheduled efficiently. But you can go too far; make sure that the workflow that is implemented is the workflow you want.

Comment: Ok, so if I write code like: await someMethod1(); await someMethod2(); await someMethod3(); that is magically going to make the app more responsive? That's what I'm not getting I guess. If you awaited on all 3 at the end, then yeah, you're running the 3 methods in parallel. Can you "dumb it down" a bit :). In the case I just mentioned, isn't it not going to run method2() until method1() is done?

Comment: Imagine a high through-put webserver, then Imagine a database call on every web page hit. If you block the current thread on a method that queries a database on another server, then eventually you will get thread pool starvation, and no more requests can be services, whereas, await free's up the current thread to respond to other requests, but the database call will be continued in the correct place.

Comment: Hmm... I guess Kirlacs response where once you go async in one place it propagates everywhere is one part of the answer... in your toast example, this kind of brings me back to "long running" operations. If you look at the source I was talking about (https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/OpenIdConnectServerHandler.Revocation.cs)... some of the methods are so trivial, I guess I'm not seeing why those trivial methods are also async. Is it just because async propogates... why make a simple new up async is the question I guess.

Comment: I get that `await SomeAsyncMethod();` won't magically create another thread by itself, but presumably SomeAsyncMethod uses parallelism internally? I'm having a difficult time understanding how asynchronous programming can be possible without using parallelism _somewhere_. Like, how do you tell the program to get started on the toast while waiting for the eggs without `DoEggs()` running concurrently, at least internally?

Comment: @Abion47: I'll update the answer.

Comment: In your last example, what would be the difference between `eggtask = FryEggAsync(); egg = await eggtask; toasttask = MakeToastAsync(); toast = await toasttask;` and `egg = await FryEggAsync(); toast = await MakeToastAsync();`? I assume it calls them synchronously but executes them asynchronously? I have to admit I've never even bothered to await the task separately before.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I've addressed your concern in an update to the answer.

Comment: Your edit definitely made something click ("the rest of the method is signed up as the continuation") and made me realize that my question wasn't entirely what I had in mind. [This](https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/0d55490a4276b97a9f6291eeccd2c4ff) should describe it more accurately: by calling the task-returning method as early as possible but awaiting as late as possible, it continues to execute the main body of code up until the actual `await`. By doing the `await` on the first line, the rest of that method is kept until after the async call has completed.

Comment: To sum up my followup question: is there a case to be made to call `Task`-returning methods as early as possible but awaiting them as late as possible?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I'll make another update.

Comment: @EricLippert Your last update is not quite good as you don't wait for any result from `Delay` and you could provide there blocking solution like normal not async function. I know that `Task.Delay` release resources for another threads but for your main function it doesn't matter. `await Task.Delay(3000);` is just a syntax solution and not describe idea of your way of thinking.

Comment: @Logman: What keeps on getting updates from the player and refreshing the UI if we're blocking on the delay step?  Why do you believe that "resources of other threads" are relevant? There need not be any other threads. What do you mean by a "syntax solution"? and I'm not sure why you think that my example, which illustrates non-data-dependent workflows, is not what I am thinking of when I think about dataflows that do not have data dependencies.

Comment: @EricLippert ok I will explain myself ;). Lets create one normal function `void deley3s(){ await Task.Delay(3000); }`. Now replace `await Task.Delay(3000);` with new function. Your main function is 100% synchronous now and not need to have any asynchronous elements. And now syntax part you could easily replace `await Task.Delay(3000);` with `Thread.Sleep(3000);`.

Comment: @Logman: Your ideas here are *completely wrong*; I suggest that you study how asynchronous delays work and why it does not work to hide the await inside a void function.  Consider actually building a little program with these different workflows and you will quickly see why you've made false equivalences.

Comment: @EricLippert It's probably you not getting my point of view. Yes I fast forward my deley3s function (as comment is too smal for real answer) just swap `await Task.Delay(3000);` to `Task.Delay(3000).wait();` or to `Thread.Sleep(3000);`. My point is you not gaining anything by using await Task.Delay(3000) you could completely omit it and make synchronous function for what you present and inside deley3s you could provide any solution of synchronization and resource managing.

Comment: @EricLippert don't get me wrong I understand your examples but way of haw you say about them is confusing. Without a proper context your examples are unclear.

Comment: @EricLippert This post made all of the Await/Async perfectly clear to me Thanks for spending the time to make a huge Comprehensive post!

Comment: This is the kind of answer StackOverflow was invented for. Bravo @EricLippert!

Comment: > While the egg is frying, stare at the egg. I lol'd.

Comment: Is there a place I can read up on how await is actually implemented. You did a great job on explaining on what it does, I'm curious on seeing the back bones of it.

Comment: @MooingRawr: This article was written while we were designing the feature; the exact details of the code generated are not accurate in this article, but it gets across the basic ideas pretty well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456403.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is because once asynchronous functions play nicer with other async functions, otherwise you start losing the benefits of asynchronicity. As a result, functions calling async functions end up being async themselves and it spreads throughout the entire application eg. if you made your interactions with a data store async, then things utilising that functionality tend to get made as async as well.

> As you convert synchronous code to asynchronous code, you’ll find that it works best if asynchronous code calls and is called by other asynchronous code—all the way down (or “up,” if you prefer). Others have also noticed the spreading behavior of asynchronous programming and have called it “contagious” or compared it to a zombie virus. Whether turtles or zombies, it’s definitely true that asynchronous code tends to drive surrounding code to also be asynchronous. This behavior is inherent in all types of asynchronous programming, not just the new async/await keywords.

Source: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**It's an Actor Model World, Really...**

My view is that async / await are simply a way of dressing up software systems so as to avoid having to concede that, really, a lot of systems (especially those with a lot of network comms) are better seen as Actor model (or better yet, Communicating Sequential Process) systems.

With both of these the whole point is that you wait for one of several things to become complete-able, take the necessary action when one does, and then return to waiting. Specifically you're waiting for a message to arrive from somewhere else, reading it, and acting on the content. In *nix, the waiting is generally done with a call to epoll() or select().

Using await / async is simply a way of pretending that your system is still kinda synchronous method calls (and therefore familiar), whilst making it difficult to efficiently cope with things not consistently completing in the same order every time.

However, once you get over the idea that you're no longer calling methods but simply passing messages to and fro it all becomes very natural. It's very much a "please do this", "sure, here's the answer" thing, with many such interactions intertwined. Wrapping it up with a big WaitForLotsOfThings() call at the top of a loop is merely an explicit acknowledgement that your program will wait until it has something to do in response to many other programs communicating with it.

**How Windows Makes it Hard**

Unfortunately, Windows makes it very hard to implement a reactor system ("if you read that message now, you'll get it"). Windows is proactor ("that message you asked me to read? It's now been read."). It's an important distinction.

First, I'll explain reactor and proactor.

- A reactor "reacts" to events. For example, if a socket becomes ready to read, only at that point does the "reactor" model program decide what to read and what to do with it.
- Whereas a proactor proactively decides what it's going to do if and when the socket becomes ready, and commits to that action.

With a reactor, a message (or indeed a timeout) that means "stop listening to that other actor" is easily dealt with - you simply exclude that other actor from the list you'll listen to next time you wait (the next call to `select()` or `epoll()`).

With a proactor, it's a lot harder. How does one honour a "stop listening to that other actor" message when the socket `read()` has already been started with some sort of async call, which won't complete until something is read? A completed `read()` is a doubtful outcome given the instruction recently received?

I'm nit-picking to some extent. Reactor is very useful in systems with dynamic connectivity, Actors dropping into the system, dropping out again. Proactor is fine if you have a fixed population of actors with comms links that'll never go away. Nevertheless, given that a proactor system is easily implemented in a reactor platform, but a reactor system cannot easily be implemented on a proactor platform (time won't go backwards), I find Window's approach particularly irritating.

So one way or other, async / await are definitely still in proactor land.

**Knock on Impact**

This has infected many other libraries.

C++'s Boost asio is also proactor, even on *nix, largely it seems because they wanted to have a Windows implementation.

ZeroMQ, which is an reactor framework, is limited to some extent on Windows being based on a call to select() (which in Windows works on only sockets).

For the cygwin family of POSIX runtimes on Windows, they had to implement select(), epoll(), etc. by having a thread per file descriptor *polling* (yes, ***polling***!!!!) the underlying socket / serial port / pipe for incoming data in order to recreate POSIX's routines. Yeurk! The comments on the cygwin dev's mailing lists dating back to the time when they were implementing that part make for amusing reading.

**Actor Isn't Necessarily Slow**

It's worth noting that the phrase "passing messages" doesn't necessarily mean passing copies around - there's plenty of formulations of the Actor Model where you're merely passing ownership of references to messages around (e.g. Dataflow, part of the Task Parallel library in C#). This makes it fast. I've not yet got round to looking at the Dataflow library, but it doesn't really make Windows reactor all of a sudden. It doesn't give you an actor model reactor system working on all sorts of data bearers like sockets, pipes, queues, etc.

**Windows 10's Linux Runtime**

So having just blasted Windows and it's inferior proactor architecture, one intriguing point is that Windows 10 now runs Linux binaries under WSL1. How, I'd very much like to know, has Microsoft implemented the system call that underlies select(), epoll() in WSL1 given that it has to function on sockets, serial ports, pipes and everything else in the land of POSIX that is a file descriptor, when everything else on Windows can't? I'd give my hind teeth to know the answer to that question.

Comment: Interesting comment, especially the first section, but I found it a bit jarring how you started talking about proactor and reactor concepts without any real introduction.

Comment: @O'Rooney, worse still I got proactor and reactor consistently the wrong way round. I've corrected that, but I'll also add something to ease the jarring dive into it! Watch this space